# how to repeat values at certain indicies twice in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have this numpy array:
`vals = numpy.array([10,20,30,40,50])`
`ind = numpy.array([0,3,4])`
I want to duplicate twice each value in `vals` at each index in `ind` so the result would be:
`res = [ 10 10 20 30 40 40 50 50 ]`

Comment: look at `np.repeat`

Comment: @hpaulj I looked at it before, didn't solve the problem

Comment: @hpaulj could you show a solution with `np.repeat` ? That was my first attempt to solve it and failed... I'd be curious if it is possible to implement the "condition" on repeat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A neat way to produce the desired result would be to use `numpy.insert`:

```
vals = numpy.array([10,20,30,40,50])
ind = numpy.array([0,3,4])
res = list(numpy.insert(vals, ind, vals[ind]))
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[10, 10, 20, 30, 40, 40, 50, 50]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [2]: vals = numpy.array([10,20,30,40,50])
   ...: ind = numpy.array([0,3,4])
```

Build a repetition array like:

```
In [3]: reps = np.ones(vals.shape[0], int)
In [4]: reps[ind]+=1
In [5]: reps
Out[5]: array([2, 1, 1, 2, 2])
In [6]: np.repeat(vals,reps)
Out[6]: array([10, 10, 20, 30, 40, 40, 50, 50])
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know how to do this in a vectorized way, but you could just write a function to do it:

```
def dupe_at_indices(array, indices):
    for i, v in enumerate(array):
        yield v
        if i in indices:
            yield v

res = list(dupe_at_indices(vals, set(ind)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I did what i knew, so here is my answer.

```
import numpy

vals = numpy.array([10,20,30,40,50])
ind = numpy.array([0,3,4])

x = ""

for i in ind:
    x += str(vals[i]) + " " + str(vals[i]) + " "

print("[" + x + "]")
```

You may be confused about "[" and "]", sorry but this is what i can do now, at least it is doing what you wanted, good luck!

Comment: He's interested in making a new `numpy` array.  The focus isn't on the string representation of those arrays.  As an aside, repeated string concatenation is slow.  It's better to collect all the substrings in a list (list append is faster), and use `join` to make one string at the end.

Comment: this does not solve the problem the OP is asking for. your result is: `[10 10 40 40 50 50 ]`